# django change list display column name with foreign field value

Tags: python, django

I am using `django 1.9` , i have following model which have two foreing fields,

**models.py**

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    owner = model.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

now i want to build a admin interface for `Mobile` model where i want to provide list display for both `product` and `owner` foreign  fields,that is, the list display will show one of the field of that foreign fields and also want to change the column name,i have tried so but its not working at all

**admin.py**

```
class MobileModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('name','product', 'owner')

    def related_product(self, obj):
        return obj.product.name
    related_product.short_description = 'product name'

    def related_owner(self, obj):
        return obj.owner.name
    related_owner.short_description = 'owner name'

admin.site.register(Mobile, MobileModelAdmin)
```

but neither its changing the column name nor showing the related value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do

```
list_display = ('name','related_product', 'related_owner') #means method name what you are given.
```

Comment: There's a `__str__` method in the foreignkey model, we don't have to define the related method to get the name, but really don't how to just rename the `foreignkey` filed in `list_display` your ansower helps. thanks a lot!